# Reverse complement of a sequence

Tags: c#

Problem is below: (need to write ReserveComplemenet method in c#)

---

The reverse complement of a sequence is formed by exchanging all of its nucleobases with their base complements, and then reversing the resulting sequence. The reverse complement of a DNA sequence is formed by exchanging all instances of:

- A with T
- T with A
- G with C
- C with G
- Then reversing the resulting sequence.

For example:

> Given the DNA sequence `AAGCT` the reverse complement is `AGCTT`

This method, `ReverseComplement()`, must take the following parameter:

- Reference to a DNA sequence

This method should return `void` and mutate the referenced DNA sequence to its reverse complement.

Currently, here is my code,

```
string result = z.Replace('A', 'T').Replace('T', 'A').Replace('G', 'C').Replace('C', 'G');


    string before = (result);
    return before;
```

I'm stuck and wondering how I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. When I run this I get `AAGGA` and not `AGCTT`

Comment: Well, that seems easy enough. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: i added my code above!

Comment: I've seen your edit, improved the formatting and provided an answer.

Comment: Thank you! How would i get that to return the string at the end so that i can print using Console.WriteLine(Translate("AAGCT ");

Comment: You don't. It's a void method (as requested). You do `var dna = "AAGCT"; Translate(ref dna); Console.WriteLine(dna);`

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<char, char>()
            {
                ['A'] = 'T',
                ['T'] = 'A',
                ['G'] = 'C',
                ['C'] = 'G',
            };

            var input = "AAGCT";
            var output = string.Concat(input.Select(c => dict[c]).Reverse()); // AGCTT

            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just have: `string.Concat(input.Select(c => dict[c]).Reverse());`. A string is already an array of char.

Comment: @Jimi. Right! I realized it just after turning off my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing each char, it's easier to implement using linq:

```
void Translate(ref string dna)
{
    var map = new string[] {"AGTC", "TCAG"};
    dna = string.Join("", dna.Select(c => map[1][map[0].IndexOf(c)]).Reverse());
}
```

You start with a string array that represents the mappings - then you select the mapped char for each char of the string, reverse the `IEnumerable<char>` you get from the `Select`, and use `string.Join` to convert it back to a string.

The code in the question first converts `A` to `T`, and then convert `T` to `A`, so everything that was `A` returns as an `A`, but also everything that was `T` returns as an `A` as well (same goes for `G` and `C`).

And also a non-linq solution based on a for loop and string builder (translation logic is the same):

```
void Translate(ref string dna)
{
    var map = new string[] {"AGTC", "TCAG"};
    var sb = new StringBuilder(dna.Length);
    for(int i = dna.Length-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        sb.Append(map[1][map[0].IndexOf(dna[i])]);
    }
    dna = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `var sb = new StringBuilder(dna.Length);` in order to be more efficient - we allocate memory just once.

Answer (score 1):

> When i run this i get AAGGA and not AGCTT

Because you are looking at it as a single replace, not multiple replaces:

```
z.Replace('A', 'T').Replace('T', 'A').Replace('G', 'C').Replace('C', 'G');

AAGCT
Replace('A', 'T')
TTGCT
Replace('T', 'A')
AAGCA
Replace('G', 'C')
AACCA
.Replace('C', 'G')
AAGGA
```

Instead what I would recommend is intermediary replace:

```
var z = "AAGCT";
var chars = z.Replace('A', '1')
  .Replace('T', 'A')
  .Replace('1', 'T')
  .Replace('G', '2')
  .Replace('C', 'G')
  .Replace('2', 'C')
  .Reverse()
  .ToArray();
var result = new string(chars);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Yields:

> AGCTT

[DotNetFIddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mtYxQ0)

Now if you're doing this millions of times, you may want to consider using a StringBuilder instead.

Recommended reading: [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Answer (score 1):

A little trick to `Replace`-version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace DNA
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var dna = "AAGCT";
            var reversed = new String(dna
                .ToLower()
                .Replace('a', 'T')
                .Replace('t', 'A')
                .Replace('g', 'C')
                .Replace('c', 'G')
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out. It is not the fastest one.

Comment: It is just the least change to your initial solution.

Comment: Better use my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or good old `StringBuilder`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace DNA
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var dna = "AAGCT";
            var sb = new StringBuilder(dna.Length);
            for(var i = dna.Length - 1; i >- 1; i--)
            {
                switch(dna[i])
                {
                    case 'A':
                        sb.Append('T');
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                        sb.Append('A');
                        break;
                    case 'G':
                        sb.Append('C');
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        sb.Append('G');
                        break;
                }
            }
            var reversed = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be faster than replacing.

Comment: Dictionary-based solution vs this one needs benchmarking to check which is faster.